# Operations that are commutative but non-associative on a set of only two elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a simple set of two arbitrary elements $E =$ {$a,b$}. I want to find an operation which is commutative but not associative. How do I go about this? Also, testing associativity with elements of this set would require me to use the same elements more than once, right? For example:

$$a * (b * a) \ne (a * b) * a,$$

as well as

$$
a * (a * a) \ne (a * a) * a.
$$

My trouble is, I don't even understand how this could be done, am I misunderstanding something about the exercise? If $*$ is commutative, then $a * (b * a)$ = $a * (a * b)$ = $(a * b) * a$, thus making the law associative. What's wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that there might not be many examples (you could actually write down all the $2^4=16$ possible multiplication tables and see how many are commutative and/or associative), but here is one example:

Define $a*b = b*a = a*a = b$ and $b*b=a$. Clearly this operation is commutative. But it is not associative, because for instance $(a*b)*b=a \neq b = a*(b*b)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a little confused, though. What exactly is the operation here? Is it that $a * a = b$ and $b * b = a$? If so, why does it commutative? Sorry if I'm being slow.

Comment: Well, you have two elements, hence $4$ possible products: $a*a, a*b, b*a, b*b$. As long as you do not have specific requirements on the operation, you can just choose each one of this products to be either $a$ or $b$. The only possible way to not have commutativity is when $a*b \neq b*a$, because clearly $a*a = a*a$ and $b*b = b*b$. In my answer $a*b = b*a = b$ by definition, so the operation is commutative. As you have seen, there are not many ways for associativity to go wrong either: $(a*a)*a=a*(a*a), (b*b)*b = b*(b*b), (a*b)*a=a*(b*a)$ and $(b*a)*b=b*(a*b)$ by commutativity.

Comment: So the only possibilities for associativity to fail are $(a*b)*b \neq a*(b*b)$ or $(a*a)*b \neq a*(a*b)$ or the other two cases obtained exchanging $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The fact that $a*a=b$ and $b*b=a$ is no obstruction to commutativity.

Comment: Oooh, I see. That's quite interesting, I didn't really think about how you could just define the operation that way, but as you said, it has no requirements, so there's no reason we can't. Thank you very much for your help.